# Raspberry Pi audio/microphone on Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I'm using the Raspberry Pi for Android Things and have it hooked up to a monitor via HDMI. Previously I was using the iMX7D board and was using the 3.5mm port for a microphone and speaker. On the Raspberry Pi, it seems to be routing that through the HDMI port.

I've searched this up and I can find that some users are able to modify the Raspberry Pi config settings, but that seems to be with Raspbian or a similar OS. Is there a way to do this on a Raspberry Pi running Android Things? Or is my option only to use a USB microphone?

Comment: "Or is my option only to use a USB microphone?" - seems it's your option.

Comment: So there's no way to use the 3.5mm headphone port?